# Changing span content with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm quite new with jasascript and jQuery and I'm trying to create a pop-up that will appear when a user have reach an achivement. This pop-up will have the user name and the tittle of the achivement. 
Here's the HTML

```
<div class="popUp">
    <img src="" alt="avatar" id="imgPop"/>
    <h3 class="nomUser"><span></span></h3>
    <p class="popAtteint">A atteint l'objectif:</p>
    <p class="objAtteint"><span></span></p>
</div>
```

and this is the javascript

```
function afficher(nom,objectif){
    if(!$(".nomUser").length){
        $(".nomUser").append("<span></span>");
    }
    if(!$(".objAtteint").length){
        $(".objAtteint").append("<span></span>");
    }
    $(".nomUser span").append(nom);
    $(".objAtteint span").append(objectif);
    $(".popUp").animate({opacity:100},1000);
    $(".popUp").delay(1000).animate({opacity:0},2000,function(){
        $(".nomUser span").remove();
        $(".objAtteint span").remove();
    });
}
```

the first time it *pop up* it works perfecly but it doesn't any other time... I think the problem is that my "if" aren't working and i can't figure out why.

(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two if statements checking the length aren't checking for the presence of the right element, which is causing your selector that's trying to append to not find anything.

The first time through your dom looks like:

```
<div class="nomUser">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

but the second time through, it would look like:

```
<div class="nomUser">
</div>
```

When the code to append 'nom' is run, it doesn't execute because it can't find a span nested under an element with the nomUser class

```
$(".nomUser span").append(nom); // Not found :-(
```

The following should work:

```
function afficher(nom,objectif){
    if(!$(".nomUser span").length){
        $(".nomUser").append("<span></span>");
    }
    if(!$(".objAtteint span").length){
        $(".objAtteint").append("<span></span>");
    }        
    $(".nomUser span").append(nom);
    $(".objAtteint span").append(objectif);
    $(".popUp").animate({opacity:100},1000);
    $(".popUp").delay(1000).animate({opacity:0},2000,function(){
        $(".nomUser span").remove();
        $(".objAtteint span").remove();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 !$(".nomUser").length
```

This means there is not such element. Use

```
if ($(".nomUser").text().length == 0)
```

If you want to check it on empty